# How to use Clob datatype in a table for a particular column, which can store limitless characters (paragraph)? As i am beginner in the field

Tags: oracle, types, sqlplus, clob

Am using CLOB datatype for a particular column but it cannot store large characters or paragraphs in it.

Comment: Could you please add some code which explains what you have tried already? Using a column with datatype clob should be straight forward.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Once the data is in the CLOB, it's easy to use indeed, but what's less easy for beginners is to put some data in it while testing in an IDE like SQLDevelopper, because string are limited to 4000 chars (unless EXTENDED chars setup in DB parameters) even when concatenating smaller pieces, and most beginners ignore the q'' string syntax to enter NL/CR/TAB characters ("paragraph"...),  will not think using CHR(), etc. Also beginners will not jump immediately into PL/SQL, external table, sqlldr , ... to load data in a CLOB column.

Comment: SQL> create table tc(c clob);


1  insert into tc(c) values(to_clob('
  2  At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis vooloribus asperiores repellat'));

Comment: This in returns on runtime, just paragraphs first single line, however the main concern is that it should be print the whole characters of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As code is attached below. This is how I stored a limitless paragraph and printed that at runtime, their code is attached in the second block.

```
CREATE TABLE CLOB_TEST
(
ID NUMBER,
TXTPARA CLOB
);
INSERT INTO CLOB_TEST(ID, TEXTPARA) VALUES(1, 'gshdhgksghgsdkgsdgjk..');
```

Usually Clob stores all the characters of paragraphs. However, it shows a single line on runtime, the main issue was to extend the display limit such that to set the maximum width in (bytes) for displaying BLOB, BFILE, CLOB, LONG, NCLOB, and XMLType values, and for copying LONG values. The command is as follows:

```
SET LONG 2000000000
SELECT *FROM CLOBTEST;
```